# The inserted conditional code regex for Raku

Tags: raku

How to do the inserted conditional code regex in Raku regex
As analogue to its Perl regex

```
 my $F = 1;
 'foobarbar' =~ / (?(?{  $F  }) foo |  bar ) bar /x  ;
```

Please help out after tried so hard a day to no avail, thanks.

Comment: Well, you need to use `~~` for regex matching, for starters... That still errors, but it's a start.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Quick answer

```
my $F = 1;
'foobarbar' ~~ / (<?{  $F  }> foo |  bar ) bar /  ;
say $/; # use `say` to get a "human friendly" `gist` of a value
```

displays:

```
｢foobar｣
 0 => ｢foo｣
```

whereas:

```
my $F = 0;
'foobarbar' ~~ / (<?{  $F  }> foo |  bar ) bar /  ;
put $/; # use `put` to get a simple computer stringification of a value
```

displays:

```
barbar
```

## Quicker answers

> Please help out after tried so hard a day to no avail, thanks.

You are more than welcome to keep asking questions here on SO. We will do our best to answer the same day you ask, and the Qs you ask and answers we provide will help everyone. So, thanks for asking, and keep them coming. That said, there are ***much* quicker ways to get answers**, and they're typically better answers than we can provide here:

1. **"Chat"** (Even if you don't like participating in real-time discussions, still read **Chat logs** below.)

   If you *like* real-time discussion, there are IRC, Discord etc channels.

   You can ask or answer questions, or more generally [enjoy yourself](https://raku.org/fun/), in real-time, right now, by clicking [web page that will take you to the `#raku-beginners` IRC channel](https://kiwiirc.com/nextclient/irc.libera.chat/#raku-beginner) to visit a Raku noob "chat" channel. If any Rakoons are around (we're currently mostly English speaking folk living in Europe or the US, though that'll hopefully expand in coming years), you'll typically get friendly engagement in a few minutes.

   There are several other channels. Click the logs link below to see a list.
2. **Chat logs**

   Chat channels are (normally) publicly [logged and searchable](https://logs.liz.nl/home.html). More than a dozen mines containing something like a million diamonds in the rough -- comments made by Rakoons and visitors in real time continuously since 2005.

   For many purposes, searching these logs is *vastly* richer pickings than googling (which is frequently useless). For example, googling the doc site for matches of `\Q` (a Perl escape that has a Raku equivalent) lists 50 false positives with just [one true positive](https://docs.raku.org/language/5to6-nutshell#Capturing_the_standard_output_of_executables.), whereas [a search for `\Q` in the old Raku channel](https://logs.liz.nl/search.html?query=%5CQ&type=words&nicks=&channel=perl6&message-type=&from-yyyymmdd=2005-02-26&to-yyyymmdd=2020-04-14) displays a long list of matches, and my brief review of them suggests many of them are useful.

   Search features include filtering by nick. For example, [a search for comments by `TimToady` (Larry Wall) containing the word `macro`](https://logs.liz.nl/search.html?query=macro&type=words&nicks=TimToady&channel=perl6&message-type=&from-yyyymmdd=2005-02-26&to-yyyymmdd=2020-04-14).

   You can even use Raku regexes! (If you do, please be thoughtful. For example, to avoid timeouts you may need to break a search into several submissions, each spanning less than 15 years.)

   In summary, you can not only search nearly two decades worth of Rakoons and non Rakoon visitors making unimaginably terrible jokes while productively discussing every bit of code (in Raku or any other PL) and every Raku topic that anyone has cared to discuss, but also search with precision to keep the signal to noise ratio high.
3. **Doc** If you want to search and read documentation, follow my guide below to quickly get answers to many questions from [doc.raku.org](https://docs.raku.org/), the main doc website:

   - **Search** The doc site's search box (top right of the website) is more useful than it might seem. You may not know what to type in. Even if you know what to type in, it may not be in the doc. Even if it *is* in the doc, it might not be included in the drop-down list of matches. But you should still try because there's an often overlooked **"search the entire site" option** listed at the very bottom of the drop-down (after all the listed matches).

     For example, if you type `condition` into the search box, and select the "Search the entire site for **condition**" entry, you'll see the matches on the doc site as seen by google. If you then browse through them you'll see the `<?{condition}> yes-pattern | no-pattern` example. *You could have found the answer to your Q in about two minutes flat by just popping `condition` in the search box!*

     BTW, if searching does *not* work for you, please feel free to provide feedback about what you tried and failed to find. (And thanks if you do.)
   - **Read** Sometimes search won't get you the answer but it's still worth reading doc because you just aren't using the right words in the search box. **For quick access to the most important parts of the doc website relevant to questions like yours** -- *especially how to transfer knowledge of another PL to Raku* -- click on the word **Language** in the green area at the top of the doc site. This will take you to the [**Raku Language**](https://docs.raku.org/language.html) tab, which includes great info as follows:

     - There are "Language X to Raku" [Migration guides](https://docs.raku.org/language.html#Migration_guides) that show how to do things in Raku that are equivalent to doing them in some other PL. You should definitely take advantage of The Perl to Raku guide. (We'd appreciate feedback about it too.) It's broken into six parts so far; you should start with the [Perl to Raku guide - in a nutshell](https://docs.raku.org/language/5to6-nutshell). In it you'll see a [Special matchers generally fall under the `<>` syntax](https://docs.raku.org/language/5to6-nutshell#Special_matchers_generally_fall_under_the_%3C%3E_syntax) section; it provides this example (slightly modified):

       ```
       (?{condition)) yes-pattern | no-pattern     # Perl
       becomes
       <?{condition}> yes-pattern | no-pattern     # Raku
       ```
     - There's also *detailed language reference* info. The **Language** tab's [Fundamental topics](https://docs.raku.org/language.html#Fundamental_topics) section includes a [Regexes](https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes) page; in it you'll find a [Regex Boolean condition check](https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Regex_Boolean_condition_check) section that contains a whole section entirely dedicated to what you've asked about.

There are of course many more resources (especially [the old design speculation docs](https://design.raku.org/)), but hopefully the above will help you find answers to many questions more quickly. Good luck!

Comment: @itilmemekcantik not ignorant, just learning (like the rest of us)!

Answer (score 7):

This will work:

```
my $F=1
'foobar' ~~ / ^^ "{ $F ?? "foo" !! "bar" }" bar /; # ｢foobar｣
$F=0
'foobar' ~~ / ^^ "{ $F ?? "foo" !! "bar" }" bar /; # Nil
```

Code blocks in regexes will be run, but unless you convert them explicitly to strings (via quotes) they will be discarded.