# What Raku regex modifier makes a dot match a newline (like Perl's /s)?

Tags: regex, newline, raku

How do I make the dot (`.`) metacharacter match a newline in a Raku regex?  In Perl, I would use the [dot matches newline modifier](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#s) (`/s`)?

Comment: This question previously contained two unrelated questions, but I split the second question into [its own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71057626/escaping-metacharacters-in-a-raku-regex-like-perls-quotemeta-or-q-e) to make both clearer easier for future users to find via a search.  (I believe this is acceptable/a good idea based on the SO meta question: [Is it acceptable to split a question into two different questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385875/is-it-acceptable-to-split-a-question-into-two-different-questions))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TL;DR** The Raku equivalent for "Perl dot matches newline" is `.`, and for `\Q...\E` it's `...`.

There are ways to get *better* answers (more authoritative, comprehensive, etc than SO ones) to most questions like these more *easily* (typically just typing the search term of interest) and *quickly* (typically seconds, couple minutes tops). I address that in this answer.

## What is Raku equivalent for "Perl dot matches newline"?

Just `.`

If you run the following Raku program:

```
/./s
```

you'll see the following error message:

```
Unsupported use of /s.  In Raku please use: .  or \N.
```

If you type `.` in the doc site's search box it lists several entries. One of them is [`. (regex)`](https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Wildcards). Clicking it provides examples and says:

> An unescaped dot `.` in a regex matches any single character. ...
> Notably `.` also matches a logical newline `\n`

My guess is you either didn't look for answers before asking here on SO (which is fair enough -- I'm not saying don't; that said you can often easily get good answers nearly instantly if you look in the right places, which I'll cover in this answer) or weren't satisfied by the answers you got (in which case, again, read on).

In case I've merely repeated what you've already read, or it's not enough info, I will provide a better answer below, after I write up an *initial* attempt to give a similar answer for your `\Q...\E` question -- and *fail* when I try the doc step.

## What is Raku equivalent for Perl `\Q...\E`?

`'...'`, or `$foo` if the `...` was metasyntax for a variable name.

If you run the following Raku program:

```
/\Qfoo\E/
```

you'll see the following error message:

```
Unsupported use of \Q as quotemeta.  In Raku please use: quotes or
literal variable match.
```

If you type `\Q...\E` in the doc site's search box it lists just one entry: [`Not in Index (try site search)`](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Adocs.raku.org+%5CQ...%5CE). If you go ahead and try the search as suggested, you'll get matching pages according to google. For me the third page/match listed (*Perl to Raku guide - in a nutshell*: "using `String::ShellQuote` (because `\Q…\E` is not completely right) ...") is the only true positive match of `\Q...\E` among 27 matches. *And it's obviously **not** what you're interested in*.

So, searching the doc for `\S...\E` appears to be a total bust.

---

How does one get answers to a question like "what is the Raku equivalent of Perl's `\Q...\E`?" if the doc site ain't helpful (and one doesn't realize Rakudo happens to have a built in error message dedicated to the exact thing  of interest and/or isn't sure what the error message means)? What about questions where neither Rakudo nor the doc site are illuminating?

SO is one option, but what lets folk interested in Raku frequently get good/great answers to their questions *easily* and *quickly* when they can't get them from the doc site because the answer is hard to find or simply doesn't exist in the docs?

## Easily get better answers more quickly than asking SO Qs

The docs website doesn't always yield a good answer to simple questions. Sometimes, as we clearly see with the `\Q...\E` case, it doesn't yield *any answer at all* for the relevant search term.

Fortunately there are several other easily searchable sources of rich and highly relevant info that often work when the doc site does not for certain kinds of info/searches. This is especially likely if you've got precise search terms in mind such as `/s` or `\Q...\E` and/or are willing browse info provided it's high signal / low noise. I'll introduce two of these resources in the remainder of this answer.

## Archived "spec" docs

Raku's design was written up in a series of "spec" docs written principally by Larry Wall over a 2 decade period.

(The word "specs" is short for "specification speculations". It's both ultra authoritative detailed and precise **spec**ifications of the Raku language, authored primarily by Larry Wall himself, and mere **spec**ulations -- because it was all subject to implementation. And the two aspects are left entangled, and now out-of-date. So don't rely on them 100% -- but *don't ignore them* either.)

The "specs", aka design docs, are a fantastic resource. You can search them using google by entering your search terms in the search box at [design.raku.org](https://design.raku.org/).

---

A search for `/s` lists 25 pages. The only useful match is [Synopsis 5: Regexes and Rules](https://design.raku.org/S05.html) ("24 Jun 2002 — There are no `/s` or `/m` modifiers (changes to the meta-characters replace them - see below)." Click it. Then do an in-page search for `/s`  (note the space). You'll see 3 matches:

> There are no `/s` or `/m` modifiers (changes to the meta-characters replace them - see below)

> A dot `.` now matches any character including newline. (The `/s` modifier is gone.)

> `.` matches an anything, while `\N` matches an anything except what `\n` matches. (The `/s` modifier is gone.) In particular, `\N` matches neither carriage return nor line feed.

---

A search for `\Q...\E` lists 7 pages. The only useful match is again [Synopsis 5: Regexes and Rules](https://design.raku.org/S05.html) ("24 Jun 2002 — `\Q$var\E /` ..."). Click it. Then do an in-page search for `\Q`. You'll see 2 matches:

> In Raku `/ $var /` is like a Perl `/ \Q$var\E /`

> `\Q...\E` sequences are gone.

## Chat logs

I've expanded the **Quicker answers** section of [my answer to one of your earlier Qs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70942880/1077672) to discuss searching the Raku "chat logs". They are an incredibly rich mine of info with outstanding search features. Please read that section of my prior answer for clear general guidance. The rest of this answer will illustrate for `/s` and `\Q...\E`.

---

[A search for the regex `/ newline . ** ^200 '/s' /` in the old Raku channel from 2010 thru 2015](https://irclogs.raku.org/search.html?query=newline+.+**+%5E200+%27%2Fs%27&type=matches&nicks=&channel=perl6&message-type=&from-yyyymmdd=2010-01-01&to-yyyymmdd=2015-01-01) found [this match](https://irclogs.raku.org/perl6/2011-03-25.html#15:24-0002):

> . matches an anything, while \N matches an anything except what \n matches. (The /s modifier is gone.) In particular, \N matches neither carriage return nor line feed.

Note the shrewdness of my regex. The pattern is the word "newline" (which is hopefully not too common) followed within 200 characters by the two character sequence `/s` (which I suspect is more common than `newline`). And I constrained to 2010-2014 because a search  for that regex of the entire 15 years of the old Raku channel would tax Liz's server and time out. I got that hit I've quoted above within a couple minutes of trying to find some suitable match of `/s` (not end-of-sarcasm!).

---

[A search for `\Q` in the old Raku channel](https://irclogs.raku.org/search.html?query=%5CQ&type=words&nicks=&channel=perl6&message-type=&from-yyyymmdd=2005-02-26&to-yyyymmdd=2020-04-14) was an immediate success. Within 30 seconds of the thought "I could search the logs" I had a bunch of useful matches.

Comment: I for one enjoy the odd 'how-do-I-do-this-Perl5-idiom-in-Raku' SO question, because often I realize how much simpler (and more direct) the Raku syntax turns out to be.

Comment: @raiph: I've changed the chat log URLs to the new, more official URL `irclogs.raku.org`.

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen Ahh. Cool!

Comment: As mentioned in a comment on the Q, I split half of this Q out into [its own Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71057626/escaping-metacharacters-in-a-raku-regex-like-perls-quotemeta-or-q-e), which means that part of this A is no longer relevant (sorry about that!).  I incorporated the part of this answer that's relevant to the new Q into [a self-answer to that Q](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71057627) (I meant to just parts of this answer, but the A ended up growing a bit).  As I said in that A, if you'd like credit for the A, I'm happy for you repost it and I'll delete the self-answer.